# How to fit reducer logic that access database

Tags: redux, react-redux

Let's say you need to load some information in the UI.
To do that, you retrieve a list of entity `A` from the database, then, in that list you do some processing (like filtering and doing some calculation to create a computed property), then for each element in the resulting list of `A2`'s, you retrieve entity `B` from the database, and again do some computation. After that you send that information to update the UI.

Here is the same thing explained in a list of steps:

- I want to convert `A` to `PresentationA`
- retrieve list of `A`
- filter list of `A`
- process the result from `A` to `A2`
- retrieve `B` associated with each `A2.bID`
- with each pair `A2`/`B` create `PresentationA`
- return the list of `PresentationA`

in other words, I have to conditionally call the database in the middle of my processing logic.

How do I fit that in Redux?

Initially I'd think of sending an action as `RetrieveListOfA`, but even if I retrieve `A`'s in the action creator and pass that information to the reducer, I'd still need to access the database again for entity `B`, which cannot be done by the reducer.

It also doesn't make much sense to me to retrieve a list of `A`, send to the reducer, then have the reducer save that (with some callbacks where the rest of the processing would be inserted) in the state tree, just to send another action to continue the processing.

Let me know if the example wasn't very clear.

**Adding some code:**

```
struct A {
    let id: String
    let someProperty: Bool
    let x: Int
    let y: Int
}
struct A2 {
    let id: String
    let r: Int
}
struct B {
    let r: Int
    let someValue: String
}
struct PresentationA {
    let r: Int
    let v: String
}

let listA = [A]() // get from database

let listPresentationA = listA
    .filter({ a in
        return a.someProperty
    })
    .map({ a in
        return A2(id: a.id, r: a.x + a.y)
    })
    .map({ a2 in
        let b = B(r: 0, someValue: "") // get B associated with a2.id form database

        return PresentationA(r: a2.r + b.r, v: b.someValue)
    })

// display listPresentationA in the UI
```

Comment: Reducers should be pure functions, they move from one state to another. They should never call DB. If you could share some code I could help. Also check thunk middleware.

Comment: @PraveenPrasad I added a code example